# Instalar certificado SSL/TLS Apache Tomcat 9 con ZeroSSL No funciona

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, tls

Mi problema es que no se aplica el certificado SSL/TLS a mi dominio fullvicie.sytes.net utilizando como proveedor del certificado a [ZeroSSL](https://zerossl.com/). Si intento acceder a la web mediante la URL fullvicie.sytes.net:443 el navegador Chrome devuelve un "ha tardado demasiado tiempo en responder.". Todo lo que pueda servir para resolver la duda lo dejo a continuación:

- server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
      type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
      description="User database that can be updated and saved"
      factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
      pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443" />

    <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" maxThreads="150" 
       SSLEnabled="true" >
         <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
          <SSLHostConfig>
              <Certificate certificateKeyFile="ssl/private.key" certificateFile="ssl/certificate.crt" certificateChainFile="ssl/ca_bundle.crt" type="RSA" />
          </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">


        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>

    </Engine>

  </Service>

</Server>
```

- CMD al ejecutar Tomcat 9

> 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.054 INFORMACI├ôN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Nombre de la
> versi├│n del servidor: Apache Tomcat/9.0.44 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.056
> INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:
> Mar 4 2021 21:49:34 UTC 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.056 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log N├║mero de
> versi├│n de servidor:     9.0.44.0 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.057
> INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:
> Windows 10 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.057 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Versi├│n de
> Systema Operativo:      10.0 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.057 INFORMACI├ôN
> [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log
> Arquitectura:                      amd64 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.057
> INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.057
> INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:
> 1.8.0_241-b07 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.057 INFORMACI├ôN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Vededor JVM:
> Oracle Corporation 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.058 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:
> C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.058 INFORMACI├ôN
> [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log
> CATALINA_HOME:                     C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44
> 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.059 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
> argument:
> -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44\conf\logging.properties
> 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.060 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
> argument:
> -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.060 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
> argument:             -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 03-Aug-2021
> 18:40:20.060 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
> argument:
> -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.060 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
> argument:             -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.060
> INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
> argument:             -Dcatalina.base=C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44
> 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.061 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
> argument:             -Dcatalina.home=C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44
> 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.061 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
> argument:
> -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44\temp 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.063 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Cargada
> la biblioteca nativa APR de Apache Tomcat [1.2.26] con la versi├│n APR
> [1.7.0]. 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.064 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent
> Capacidades APR: IPv6 [true], enviar fichero [true], aceptar filtros
> [false], aleatorio [true]. 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.064 INFORMACI├ôN
> [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent
> APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
> 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.067 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL
> inicializado correctamente [OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020] 03-Aug-2021
> 18:40:20.261 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Inicializando el manejador de
> protocolo ["http-nio-80"]
>
> 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.535 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.configureUpgradeProtocol
> The ["https-openssl-apr-443"] connector has been configured to support
> negotiation to [h2] via ALPN 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.535 INFORMACI├ôN
> [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Inicializando el
> manejador de protocolo ["https-openssl-apr-443"]
>
> 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.573 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in
> [644] milliseconds 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.588 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Arrancando
> servicio [Catalina] 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.588 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet
> engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.44] 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.594 INFORMACI├ôN
> [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory
> Desplegando el directorio
> [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44\webapps\docs] de la aplicaci├│n web
> 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.738 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
> web application directory
> [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44\webapps\docs] has finished in [143] ms
> 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.739 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Desplegando el
> directorio [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44\webapps\examples] de la
> aplicaci├│n web 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.965 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
> web application directory
> [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44\webapps\examples] has finished in
> [227] ms 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.965 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Desplegando el
> directorio [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44\webapps\host-manager] de la
> aplicaci├│n web 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.989 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
> web application directory
> [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44\webapps\host-manager] has finished in
> [24] ms 03-Aug-2021 18:40:20.990 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Desplegando el
> directorio [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44\webapps\manager] de la
> aplicaci├│n web 03-Aug-2021 18:40:21.009 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
> web application directory
> [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44\webapps\manager] has finished in [19]
> ms 03-Aug-2021 18:40:21.010 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Desplegando el
> directorio [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44\webapps\ROOT] de la
> aplicaci├│n web 03-Aug-2021 18:40:21.347 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars Al menos un JAR, que se
> ha explorado buscando TLDs, a├║n no conten├¡a TLDs. Activar historial
> de depuraci├│n para este historiador para una completa lista de los
> JARs que fueron explorados y de los que nos se hall├│ TLDs. Saltarse
> JARs no necesarios durante la exploraci├│n puede dar lugar a una
> mejora de tiempo significativa en el arranque y compilaci├│n de JSP .
> Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is` com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is
> automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver
> class is generally unnecessary. NO_ERROR LISTS INITIALIZATED
> 03-Aug-2021 18:40:21.589 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
> web application directory
> [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [580] ms
> 03-Aug-2021 18:40:21.591 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
> ["http-nio-80"] 03-Aug-2021 18:40:21.597 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
> ["https-openssl-apr-443"] 03-Aug-2021 18:40:21.600 INFORMACI├ôN [main]
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [1027]
> milliseconds

- Directorio los certificados
  [image: Directorio donde se encuentra el certificado]

Cabe destacar que tengo los puertos 80, 8080, 443 y 8443 abiertos.
La URL es [fullvicie.sytes.net](http://fullvicie.sytes.net) y lo más seguro es que esta semana la web esté en funcionamiento.

Comment: Pregunta inocente, ¿has reiniciado el Apache?

Comment: @fredyfx mil veces

Comment: ¿Por qué tantas veces si con una o dos bastaba para confirmar ._.? Por otro lado, ¿cuál es la ruta de donde se encuentra tu webapp?

Comment: Quizás sea de utilidad: https://zerossl.com/help/installation/tomcat/

Comment: @fredyfx esta es la ruta del webapp: C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44\webapps\ROOT

Comment: Coloca la carpeta SSL en `C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44\webapps` y una reiniciada. Si no funciona, coloca en `C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.44\webapps\ROOT` y otra reiniciada. Probablemente solucione el tema.

Comment: @fredyfx además, siguendo los pasos de instalación me aparece el siguiente error en el paso 2 --- error de herramienta de claves: java.lang.Exception: La entrada no es un certificado X.509 --- He estado buscando soluciones y no he hallado ninguna.

Comment: @fredyfx reiniciar no es el problema. Acabo de hacer lo que me has dicho y nada.

Comment: En efecto, reiniciar no es el problema, en muchas ocasiones es parte de la solución o la solución en sí. En ese caso, ya no se me ocurre qué más realizar, intenta seguir a detalle la documentación oficial: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html Algún paso ha de haber que sea requerido. Buena suerte y mucha paciencia :D

Comment: Solucionado. Aún así, muchas gracias @fredyfx

Comment: ¡Excelente! Me alegra saberlo, sigue adelante bro :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado. El problema estaba en que había dos "Connectors" especificados en el archivo server.xml cuando solo debía de haber uno.

El archivo server.xml quedaría así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
      type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
      description="User database that can be updated and saved"
      factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
      pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" redirectPort="80">
          <SSLHostConfig>
               <Certificate certificateKeyFile="ssl/private.key" certificateFile="ssl/certificate.crt" certificateChainFile="ssl/ca_bundle.crt" type="RSA" />
          </SSLHostConfig>
     </Connector>

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">


        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>

    </Engine>

  </Service>

</Server>
```

Comment: Dato importante, regresa en 24 horas para darle click al check verde, de ese modo ayudarás a mantener la buena salud del sitio, efecto de % de preguntas resueltas.